# Extracting data from .wotreplay file

Tags: java

Im trying to extract data from .wotreplay file which is basically replay file of a battle in World Of Tanks battle.

When I put that file in JSON file reader in internet browser i can see some weird symbols and some normal text.

All i need is to read one object( named "vehicles") from that file into Java. Anyone can help?

[Link](https://www47.zippyshare.com/v/Wqbby9L6/file.html) to sample .wotreplay file.

[Highlighted](http://prntscr.com/q3ahaw) data from file that i need to get.

Sorry for my English and thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this post](http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/105682-wot-replay-file-format/), I created a simple code example with comments, which should do exactly what you want.

```
public class Main {
    private static ByteBuffer littleEndianBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    private static final int MAGIC = 0x12323411;

    private static ByteBuffer readLittleEndianBuffer(DataInputStream in, int len) throws IOException {
        littleEndianBuffer.clear();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
        int i = in.read(bytes);
        if (i < len) {
            throw new EOFException();
        }
        littleEndianBuffer.put(bytes);
        littleEndianBuffer.rewind();
        return littleEndianBuffer;
    }

    private static int readLittleEndianInt(DataInputStream in) throws IOException {
        return readLittleEndianBuffer(in, 4).getInt();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // Replace with your own file or maybe argument
        File f = new File("D:\\Downloads\\test2.wotreplay");
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        // This is probably a 'magic' value, which identifies file format. Feel free, to just ignore those bytes
        int magic = in.readInt();
        System.out.println("Magic matches: " + (magic == MAGIC));
        // Seems to contain the value of the winning team (1 or 2)
        int winner = readLittleEndianInt(in);
        System.out.println("Winner: " + winner);
        // The size of JSON string is in little endian order, so we need to reverse it to big endian (96 54 00 00 -> 00 00 54 96)
        int size = readLittleEndianInt(in);
        System.out.println("Json length: " + size);
        // Read all bytes and create string from bytes
        byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
        System.out.println("Size matches: " + (in.read(bytes) == size));
        System.out.println(new String(bytes));
    }

}
```

I would comment to existing answer, but I don't have enough reputation on stack to comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this forum post](http://forum.worldoftanks.eu/index.php?/topic/105682-wot-replay-file-format/) and the research done by that poster (credits to him/her) you can get the required info by reading the file:

1. Ignore first 8 bytes (1-8)
2. Read the next 4 bytes (9-12) as an `int`. This is the length of the first chunk, which is the one you need. Let's refer to it as `chuck1length`.
3. Read the next `chuck1length` bytes (starting from byte 13) as a String.
4. Parse the string as JSON.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I have just developed a python package to do exactly this. 
It extracts data from .wotreplay files and stores the results into a local database.

https://pypi.org/project/wotreplay/1.0.0/